# Boostrap mobile menu doesn't open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap menu doesn't work on mobile. I checked several times, but can't see error. All looks good, `id` and `data-target` are correct.

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#main-header" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">
                <img alt="Brand" src="assets/img/logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#main-header">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="/demo">Demo1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/demo">Demo1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <p class="navbar-text">
                        Welcome, M1 D1
                    </p>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cepokojome/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change menu Id

```
id="#main-header"
```

to

```
id="main-header"
```

Comment: Ohhh, I think I need to go to sleep. Thank you.